# Adding Python-twisted in yocto build

Tags: python, yocto

I have added python-twisted in local.conf

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-twisted"
```

after building the os and putting it on my board , i ran following command:

```
pip list
```

I get that twisted v17.9.0 is present

but when i try to run an application which requires python twisted ,twisted asks for dependencies (hyperlink,six,autobahn,automat etc.)

so i have to download packages on my board and install them or by connecting board to internet and install twisted using pip.

How to install and ensure that all the dependencies required by python-twisted is build during yocto build itself ?

Answer (score 1):

Yocto does fine grained packaging of python-twisted, therefore it has multiple output packages generated in the end. So its important to know which ones are needed on target.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-twisted-core"
```

might cover most core pieces then there are more see

here is full list of [python-twisted packages](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python-twisted.inc#n21)

Comment: I am using yocto rocko its having following line

Comment: RDEPENDS_${PN}-core = "python-core python-zopeinterface python-contextlib"

Comment: I doesn't have hyperlink,constantly even in the downloads of yocto,how to add  them